# Cauchy-Schwarz, how does it work in this example?

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

> Consider $\|\cdot\|_2$ such that $\|x\|_2 = \left(\sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|^2\right)^{1/2}$.

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}, x\in \mathbb{R}^n$, then

$$\begin{align}
\|Ax\|_2^2 & = \sum_{i=1}^n y_i^2 & \text{ if } Ax = y\\
& = \sum_{i=1}^n \left[\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}x_j\right]^2\\
& \color{red}{\leqslant} \sum_{i=1}^n \left( \sum_{k=1}^n a_{ik}^2\right)\cdot \left( \sum_{l=1}^n x_l^2\right)\\
& \ldots\\
& \leqslant \|A\|_2^2 \cdot \|x\|_2^2
\end{align}$$

Could someone explain $\color{red}{\leqslant}$? I know Cauchy-Schwarz is involved, but I don't see how it works here.

Comment: In the definition of the 2-norm, you probably mean to raise the parenthesis to $1/2$ and not $-1/2$, right?

Comment: @mickep my bad, fixed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is precisely the application of Cauchy-Schwarz, which states:

$$||x||\cdot||y|| \geq \langle x,y\rangle,$$

or, if you square this, you get

$$||x||^2\cdot||y||^2 \geq \langle x,y\rangle^2.$$

Now, if the components of $x$ are $x_i$ and the components of $y$ are $y_i$, this equation becomes

$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2\right)\cdot \left(\sum_{i=1}^n y_i^2\right)\geq \left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_iy_i\right)^2$$

which is exactly what you have if you set $y_i = a_i$, leave the $x_i$ and replace all $i$ with $j$.

Answer (score 1):

Cauchy-Schwarz says that
$$
(a_{i1}x_1+a_{i2}x_2+\cdots+a_{in}x_n)^2\leq (a_{i1}^2+a_{i2}^2+\cdots+a_{in}^2)(x_1^2+x_2^2+\cdots+x_n^2).
$$
which is exactly that inequality you point to (note that this is just the inner sum we work on, so we do this for all $i$). If this was not what you asked for, please explain your problem more.

Answer (score 1):

This is an answer from the geometrical view of inner product.

Let $a = [a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_n]^T$ and $b = [b_1, b_2, \cdots, b_n]^T$. The inner product between $a$ and $b$, denoted as $\langle a, b \rangle$, is defined as
$$
\langle a, b \rangle = \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_ib_i
$$

Its geometrical reinterpretation shows that the following equation holds:
$$
\langle a, b \rangle = \|a\|_2 \cdot \|b\|_2 \cdot \cos \theta_{a,b}
$$
where $\|*\|_2$ is the length of a vector and $\theta_{a,b}$ is the included angle between $a$ and $b$.

Thus, we have:
$$
\langle a, b \rangle \leq \|a\|_2 \cdot \|b\|_2 \tag{1}
$$
since $\cos\theta_{a,b} \leq 1$.

Squaring both sides of (1) should clarify your problem.

Comment: that's a nice way of looking at it!

Answer (score 0):

In its more general understanding, the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality compares the inner product ($\langle\ ,\ \rangle$) of two vectors of a space with their norm ($\|\ \|$) (this does require the space to have both an inner product and the corresponding norm). It states that in such a space $E$ :

$ \forall (x,y)\in E^2\ \ \ |\langle x,y \rangle| \leq \| x\| \cdot \|y\|$.

In the case of $\mathbb{R}$ and its cartesian powers (say, the $n$th power, where $n\in\mathbb{N}$) the inner product and norm are as follows :

$ \forall (x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^n\ \ \ \langle x,y \rangle = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i\cdot y_i $

$\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n \ \ \ \| x\| = \sqrt{\langle x,x \rangle}=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2}$

Now these things seriously look like the different elements of your inequality, don't they ?

All you need to know on top of that is that you can sum inequalities almost at will - take any amount $p$ of inequalities ($p\in\mathbb{N}$) on elements $(a_1, ..., a_p)$ and $(b_1, ..., b_p)$ both taken in $\mathbb{R}^p$ :

$\forall i \in [[1,p]]\ \  a_i \leq b_i$

then it instantly follows that

$\sum_{i=1}^p a_i \leq \sum_{i=1}^p b_i$.

Play around with all of this, and you should figure it out.

(PS : Be warned though, that on the other hand if all you know is $\sum_{i=1}^p a_i \leq \sum_{i=1}^p b_i$ then all you can deduce is $\forall i \in [[1,p]]\ a_i \leq \sum_{i=1}^p b_i$)

(PPS : It seems that not all know or use the integer interval notation that I use : for $n$ and $p$ integers, $[[n,p]] = [n,p] \cap \mathbb{N}$)